# How to create chat application by using socket programming in android?

Tags: java, php, android

I'm beginner in android. I want to send any text data to server,and server response the any text data, I read this link:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

but that link just sends text, and can not get response of server, how can I solve that?

Comment: use xmpp its easier,better and faster then socket

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi thanks.can you give me link of tutorial?

Comment: similar to whatsapp?

Comment: @Shadow yes my friend

Comment: http://xmpp-tutorials.blogspot.in/  Share Your Email I Will guide You .i have been working on chat apps from last 1 year

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Follow these video :**

With "Building a Chat App for Android from Scratch", you will learn everything about chat apps, even if you've never build one before!

You can send any text data to server,and server(**XAMPP and MAMP**) response the any text data.

[image]

**See**
http://qscutter.com/courses/building-a-chat-app-for-android-from-scratch

you make script **php and Ajax** **index.php**

[image: programming ajax]

**ServerSocket** : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

**Socket** :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Thanks man enjoy..

Answer (score 6):

For complete understand of whatsapp flow let me guide you the flow of whatsapp, how to replicate similar to that.extracted from blogs that I learned and applied in project is.

1. Protocol used by WhatsApp

XMPP (Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol) is being used by WhatsApp. To ensure network security, DSL is being used. This ensures private data transfer.

when message is sent, it is queued on the server. The message waits in the queue until the recipient reconnects to receive the message. As and when a message is delivered the sender gets notified by a double check mark near the message. After the delivery the messages are instantly deleted from the server memory.

2. Database management

For the database management Mnesia DB comes into play. Mnesia is a multiuser distributed DBMS which happens to be the default DB of ERLANG. Thus by using Mnesia, the app is able to achieve quicker request responses, thereby improving the overall efficiency.

FreeBSD is the operating system upon which WhatsApp is laid upon. Improvising on the ERLANG based applications and optimizing FreeBSD, WhatsApp is able to achieve better throughput. For storing multimedia files, the app uses an exclusive web server YAWS.

the technicalities of WhatsApp it is time to shift gears over analyzing the possibilities of creating a whatsApp alternative. There are plenty of messaging applications in the market that appear to be perfect WhatsApp clones. The reality is many of the attempts of building WhatsApp like similar apps are failing because they do not follow the technical aspects

Let me explain the flow of an app that can be used to develop WhatsApp clone for Android as it has the SDK ready for these widely preferred mobile operating systems. This is the flow where you can discover it.

Ejabberd, the open source Jabber server has been customized one that you can used to improve operational efficiency. The XMPP protocol has also been customized to speedup signing in and re-signing in sessions. To protect the app from DDOS attacks and to prevent account spoofing, this mobile chat application has been encrypted with HMAC.

For data storing, you can makes use of both Mnesia and MySQL. While Mnesia is used to maintain user login sessions, MySQL contributes in maintaining the user details, right from account credentials to other personal data.

logs are a key for instant messaging applications. In order to save chat history between several nodes, You can deploy Cassandra database. This database offers a good read write speed thus helping users to retrieve chat logs as and when they need.

[image]

You can refer additional information from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/) and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/).

Hope it will help.